# Displaying multiple Thumbnails not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

So I am making this "drop-zone" for a website.

The user can drag and drop images over this area and all jpegs that are dropped on the area are displayed as thumbnailes. I made a List of all jpegs that are dropped on the area and that is working fine. Now everytime a new jpeg is added to that list I want to display all jpegs as thumbnailes of the size 100x150px.

Here is my code for that.
And here is a like to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cJkYj/2/

```
function displayThumbnailes(  ) {
    //Clear the div.
    var outerDiv = document.getElementById('fileChooserDiv');
    while (outerDiv.hasChildNodes()) {
        outerDiv.removeChild(outerDiv.lastChild);
    }
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    outerDiv.appendChild(div);
    //Go over the Files and add Thumbnails for all jpegs.
    for( var i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
        if( files.get(i).type == "image/jpeg") {    
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function() {
                var result = reader.result; 
                displayThumbnail( result, div );
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(files.get(i));
        }
    }
}

function displayThumbnail( src, div ) { 
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        var cv = document.createElement('canvas');
        cv.style.border = "1px solid #ffffff";
        cv.width = 100;
        cv.height = 150;
        var ctx = cv.getContext( "2d" );
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 150);
        div.appendChild(cv);
    }
    img.src = src;
}
```

**MY PROBLEM:** I believe this code would display all thumbnailes in the area of the div but I only see the last one.

This looks like I am messing up some synchronisation or something.
"files" is an Object that manages the files dragged on the "drop-zone".
I want every Thumbnail to have his own canvas so I can add an onclick event to them later.

Any help would be appriciated ^^

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle? Why do you place the thumbnails inside a canvas? You can add a onclick event to "normal" html elements as well.

Comment: The biggest reason for using Canvas is that I worked with canvas before and know my way around them a bit. I wanted to resize the Images to certain dimension. Well could have probably used an "img"-Element for that ^^

Comment: Are the images dragged from another div inside the page or are they dragged from the users local hard drive and dropped over the page?

Comment: The Images are dropped from outside of the page. From a file explorer.

Comment: The fiddle isn't working for me. If I drop a file nothing happens and when I click the "log files" button I get the error message that `files` is not defined

Comment: Thanks, I set it up wrong. Fixed it now, should be working.

Comment: Your `reader.onloadend`function get never called

Comment: It should get called when `reader.readAsDataURL(files.get(i));` finishes.

Comment: Like this? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cJkYj/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
reader.onloadend = function() {
    var result = reader.result; 
    displayThumbnail( result, div );
}
reader.readAsDataURL(files.get(i));
```

was failing because of the async onloadend callback.  Each pass through the loop updated the outer `reader` variable, so each event used only the last reference.

You could either change your code to wrap that in a closure:

```
(function(reader) {            
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        var result = reader.result; 
        displayThumbnail( result, div );
}})(reader);
```

or (preferred) change your code to use the event specific data :

```
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    var result = evt.target.result; 
    displayThumbnail( result, div );
};
```

-- or using onload --

```
reader.onload = function (evt) {
    var result = evt.target.result;
    displayThumbnail(result, div);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(files.get(i));
```

works: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cJkYj/4/)

I should also note that I rearranged your code to completely run within an `onload` handler.

Comment: Thanks for the help it's working great.
I just seem to have misconception there, maybe you can help me. In my original Code I was thinging that I would create a new instance of the reader each loop and such would not have the problem you described I have. I was thinking the onload would be a seperate function for each reader created. Well will have to read up on that.

Comment: That's a easy mistake to make - bites everyone from time to time.  Look at the first example  - it was passing the reader in as a param so the inner callback would have it's own local copy as a reference.  But definitely hit the books on closures, loops and scope.  A good linter (jshint or other) hooked into your editor can help catch these types of errors early on as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp going to use a linter from now on. Didn't really now about them before.